# Setting size and border properties in the Intellij Idea form editor doesn't do anything

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jpanel

I'm a beginner to java and I'm trying to write a small swing app using Intellij Idea, but i have this problem - i added another custom panel (used for custom painting) to the content pane and no matter how much i change preferred, minimum and maximum panel sizes in the property editor my app still always comes out looking like this:

[image]

the small rectangle in the middle is supposed to be the aforementioned panel border which was coded by hand by calling `setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));` inside the panel constructor. I tried setting it in the property editor but again for some reason that doesn't do anything to my actual app.

I tried using grid and border layout managers but they don't work so I tried to fix the sizing issue by overriding `getPreferredSize()` method and making it return `new Dimension(400, 300)` but even though at least my panel is drawn it's size becomes static and doesn't change even if you drag around frame borders with mouse.

**TL;DR** basically my issue is that changing panel properties in the Intellij form editor does nothing and either my panel isn't shown at all or refuses to be resized. I would appreciate any help with that.

I tried recreating this project in NetBeans and it seems to be working fine. Interestingly enough when previewing the form in the Intellij form editor it also looks to be working fine (except that it messes up the menubar) but then you actually build and run it it doesn't work.

Code for my custom JPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import circuit.*;

public class Drawing extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private Circuit circuit = null;

public Drawing() {
    //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}

public void setCircuit(Circuit circuit) {
    this.circuit = circuit;
}

/*@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 300);
}*/

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    if (circuit == null) {
        graphics.drawString("Create a new Circuit by selecting File>New.", 10, 20);
    } else {
        // draw something
    }
}
}
```

Properties of my custom panel:

[image]

Properties of my content pane:

[image]

I really liked using Intellij Idea for writing console applications but i started to understand that it's not the best IDE for beginners trying to make Swing applications.

Comment: You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method, so the layout manager can do its job. Why did you comment out that code? Don't use an IDE to generate code. You spend time learning the IDE not Java. Use the IDE to help debug. `but even though at least my panel is drawn it's size becomes static and doesn't change` - use an appropriate layout manager and the size will change if the size of the frame changes. Learn some Swing  basics by reading the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] when you ask a question. We don't know the context of how the panel is used.

Comment: I wanted to write this application for creating logic circuit diagrams. The custom panel should be used for drawing and editing circuits and nothing else. It's not going to contain any buttons or the like, only drawn content. Which layout manager would be best suited for that?

Comment: I don't understand your full requirement so I can't make a suggestion. Your originally stated: `I tried using grid and border layout managers but they don't work`. Well I fail to see why that didn't work, so as I said earlier post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem when you used those layout managers. Before you can choose which layout manager (or combination of layout manager) to use, you need to understand the basics of how layout management works, which is why you need to read the tutorial.

Comment: *"It's not going to contain any buttons or the like, only drawn content. Which layout manager would be best suited for that?"* A layout manager is irrelevant to a custom painted component that has no components inside it. It is important to the **size assigned** to that component in the parent container's layout. Post an MCVE as @camickr has been suggesting.